# Remove Option from result

Tags: scala

I would like to have the actual value instead of Option object in my result.

```
case class MyObj(id: String, objVal: List[String])

val listOfListOfIds = List(List(id1, id2, id3), List(id4, id5, id6))

val allMyObjs = List(
    MyObj("id1",List("val1a", "val1b")),
    MyObj("id2",List("val2a", "val2b")),
    MyObj("id3",List("val3a", "val3b")),
    MyObj("id4",List("val4a", "val4b")),
    MyObj("id5",List("val5a", "val5b")),
    MyObj("id6",List("val6a", "val6b"))
)

listOfListOfIds.map { _.map { id => allMyObjs.find(obj => obj.id == id).map { _.objVal map { v => Future(v) } } } }
```

returns `List[List[Option[List[scala.concurrent.Future[String]]]]]`, how to get `List[List[List[scala.concurrent.Future[String]]]]` instead ?

Comment: You can turn an `Option[List[T]]` into a possibly empty `List[T]` calling `opt.getOrElse(List.empty[T])`. The code would benefit from using case classes to have more explicit types.

Comment: Is this your actual code? I wonder why not use a `HashSet` if you want to do intersection between two collections? Also, can you flatten the list of lists?

Comment: I'd also recommend using intermediate, immutable variables, at least. I believe that the `List[List[List[scala.concurrent.Future[String]]]]` type is not clear to understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use a flatMap instead of map :

```
val res = listOfListOfIds.map {
  _.flatMap { id => allMyObjs.find(obj => obj.id == id).map { _.objVal map { v => Future(v) } } }
}
```

Comment: Yes that works, so next question is how to flatten all to get List[scala.concurrent.Future[String]] instead of List[List[List[scala.concurrent.Future[String]]]], the best I could have is List[List[scala.concurrent.Future[String]]]

Comment: it's the same principle flatMap instead of the first map and then flatten at the end

Answer (score 1):

There's an alternative solution. The source of the Option is the find() method you apply to a List:

```
allMyObjs.find(obj => obj.id == id)
```

Since find() may, or may not, find what you're looking for, it has to return an Option. The alternative is to use filter(), which will discard the items that don't comply to the predicate you pass as argument, returning only the ones that do. If you instead use the code below, the result will be a list with the values themselves:

```
> listOfListOfIds.flatMap { _.flatMap { id => allMyObjs.filter(obj => obj.id == id).flatMap {_.objVal map { v => Future (v) } } } }
res0: List[scala.concurrent.Future[String]] = List(Success(val1a), Success(val1b), Success(val2a), Success(val2b), Success(val3a), Success(val3b), Success(val4a), Success(val4b), Success(val5a), Success(val5b), Success(val6a), Success(val6b))
```

As for removing the intermediary lists, you can use flatMap() instead of map(), combined with flatten at the end as you prefer.

Cheers